# An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@d23' is not contained by this sqlparametercollection

Tags: c#

I am adding Parameters to CommandParameters collection for repeated execution; once for each datagrid row.

I am receiving this exception.

> "A SqlParameter with ParameterName '@dx' (***x represents a parameter
>   name)*** is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection"

What am I doing wrong and where?

```
try
{
   con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
   con.Open();

    string cb = "insert into feepayment(FeePaymentID,ScholarNo,FeeID,FDCourse,FDBranch,Semester,TutionFees,LibraryFees,catfees,stationaryfees,textbooksfees,swimmingfees,boardingfees,languagesfees,mealsfees,othersfees,computerfees,activityfees,insurancefees,orphansfees,diaryfees,furniturefees,maintenancefees,TotalFees,DateOfPayment,ModeOfPayment,PaymentModeDetails,TotalPaid,Fine,DueFees,PreviousTerm) VALUES (@d23,@d24,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17,@d18,@d19,@d20,@d21,@d22,@d25,@d26,@d27,@d28,@d29,@d30,@d31,@d32,@d33)";

    cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cb);

    cmd1.Connection = con;
    // Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d23", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 200, "FeePaymentID"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d24", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "ScholarNo"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "FeeId"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "FDCourse"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d3", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 30, "FDBranch"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d4", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Semester"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d5", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TutionFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d6", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "LibraryFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d7", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "catfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d8", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 15, "stationaryfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d9", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "textbookfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d10", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "swimmingfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d11", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "boardingfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d12", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "languagesfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d13", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "mealsfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d14", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "othersfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d15", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "computerfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d16", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "activityfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d17", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "insurancefees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d18", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "orphansfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d19", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "diaryfees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d20", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "furniturefees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d21", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "maintenancefees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d22", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TotalFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d25", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 30, "DateOfPayment"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d26", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "ModeOfPayment"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d27", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 200, "PaymentModeDetails"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d28", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TotalPaid"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d29", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "Fine"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d30", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "DueFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d31", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "RegistrationFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d32", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "MusicFees"));
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d33", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "PreviousTerm"));

    // Prepare command for repeated execution
    cmd1.Prepare();
    // Data to be inserted
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            invoice(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());

            cmd1.Parameters["@d23"].Value = paymentID;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d24"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            cmd1.Parameters["@d1"].Value = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters["@d2"].Value = course;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d3"].Value = branch;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d4"].Value = sem;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d5"].Value = tution;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d6"].Value = library;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d7"].Value = cat;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d8"].Value = stationary;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d9"].Value = textbook;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d10"].Value = swimming;

            if (row.Cells[3].Value.Equals("Boarder"))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters["@d11"].Value = boarding.ToString();

                cmd1.Parameters["@d22"].Value = totals.ToString();
            }
            else if (row.Cells[3].Value.Equals("Commuter"))
            {

                cmd1.Parameters["@d11"].Value = "0";
                cmd1.Parameters["@d22"].Value = (totals - boarding).ToString();

            }

            cmd1.Parameters["@d12"].Value = languages;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d13"].Value = meals;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d14"].Value = others;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d15"].Value = computer;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d16"].Value = activity;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d17"].Value = insurance;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d18"].Value = orphans;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d19"].Value = diary;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d20"].Value = furniture;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d21"].Value = maintenance;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d25"].Value = effectivedate.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d26"].Value = "";
            cmd1.Parameters["@d27"].Value = "";
            cmd1.Parameters["@d28"].Value = 0;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d29"].Value = 0;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d30"].Value = 0;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d31"].Value = registration;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d32"].Value = music;
            cmd1.Parameters["@d33"].Value = int.Parse(prevdue);

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved - r", "Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    btnSave.Enabled = false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error>>>>", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: The parameterName @d41 was a test that I was trying after the error persisted. Note, The error still gets returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try removing all of the @d41 references?

Comment: You have 31 fields and 33 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your making a post don't just dump all your code put only the important information.

There is no D41 in the insert list that I see and as DBugger said it should cmd1

```
 cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d41", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Semester"));
```

**EDIT**

Another thing your missing is your missing a parameter in your insert statement there are 34 columns and only 33 values.  You need a @d34. at the end of your insert statement

Ideally You should be putting all you information in a some kind of structure and add the parameters in a loop and construct that insert statement with a string builder as well.  It will clean your code up and make it easier to debug

Comment: The parameterName @d41 was a test that I was trying after the error persisted. Note, The error still gets returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if that solves your issue, if it does remember to mark your answer as completed,

Answer (score 1):

Missing @d41 in your Insert Statement

```
VALUES (@d23,@d24,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,
@d17,@d18,@d19,@d20,@d21,@d22,@d25,@d26,@d27,@d28,@d29,@d30,@d31,@d32,@d33)
```

You are adding parameter "@d41" to cmd and not cmd1

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d41", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Semester"));
```

And in your for loop you are trying to add a value to "@d41" which doesn't exist for the command cmd1

```
cmd1.Parameters["@d41"].Value = "";
```

Comment: The parameterName @d41 was a test that I was trying after the error persisted. Note, The error still gets returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: @[J. Doe] Did you try removing all of the "@d41" references? What is the exact error message? "@d23" not in parameter collection?